# What is causing the changes in /etc/resolver/ on MacOS Sierra to be noticed

Tags: osx, dns, resolv.conf

I wanted to use non-default DNS resolver for one specific domain, and the first idea was to simply use local dnsmasq. While looking for MacOS version, I found out that I can achieve the same simply by creating a file with domain name in `/etc/resolver/example.com`, with simple one line:

`nameserver 8.8.8.8`

All was good and works as expected, the resolution works, and `scutil --dns` confirms:

```
resolver #8
  domain   : example.com
  nameserver[0] : 8.8.8.8
  flags    : Request A records
  reach    : Reachable
```

The next thing, I wanted to share this with a friend, by creating a simple one liner that he could run in his terminal:

```
sudo mkdir -p /etc/resolver/ && echo "nameserver 8.8.8.9" | sudo tee /etc/resolver/example.net
```

Again, `scutil --dns` confirms:

```
resolver #10
  domain   : example.net
  nameserver[0] : 8.8.8.9
  flags    : Request A records
  reach    : Reachable
```

Then I noticed a typo, so I corrected the address to 8.8.8.8 and ran the line again:

```
sudo mkdir -p /etc/resolver/ && echo "nameserver 8.8.8.8" | sudo tee /etc/resolver/example.net
```

But that did not seem to have any effect:

```
resolver #10
  domain   : example.net
  nameserver[0] : 8.8.8.9
  flags    : Request A records
  reach    : Reachable
```

I checked the file content, all seemed fine:

```
$ cat /etc/resolver/example.net 
nameserver 8.8.8.8
```

And then I opened the file in `vim`, changed to `8.8.4.4` and:

```
resolver #10
  domain   : example.net
  nameserver[0] : 8.8.4.4
  flags    : Request A records
  reach    : Reachable
```

I have checked back and forth several times, when I echo the address to the file, the change has no effect, but it is enough to only open it in `vim` and not even change anything (just exit), previously echoed changes will be applied.
What is the mechanism behind this?

Comment: `Vim` is likely creating a new file and deleting the old one where `tee` is likely truncating the file and writing to it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> [It] is enough to only open it in `vim` and not even change anything (just exit), previously echoed changes will be applied.

I had to use `sudo vim` for that to work. Running it with my regular user had no effect. My theory is that whatever is watching `/etc/resolver` watches for changes to the directory, and not to changes to files within it, and the reloads everything in it when it sees a change to the directory. Vim creates a swap file, by default in the same directory as the file being edited. This is a change to the directory, and is picked up by the watcher. So, when I did:

```
sudo vim -n /etc/resolver/example.net
```

where `-n` disable swap file creation, changes to the file were no longer picked up.

Comment: indeed, `sudo touch /etc/resolver/foo` does help

Answer (score 4):

Changes to existing files in `/etc/resolver` are not noticed, it is only noticed when files are created or deleted in that folder.

It's the `IPMonitor` plugin of `configd` that monitors this folder.
From the source code:

```
status = notify_monitor_file(notify_token, resolver_directory_path, 0);
```

And what this function does is to set a monitor on the `inode` of the path. So it will only get a notification if the `inode` of `/etc/resolver` changes, not when the `inode` of any file within that directory changes.

In UNIX a directory is just like a file whose content is a table listing the directory content. Thus whenever you add or remove a file, this table is updated and thus the `inode` is updated as well, triggering the notification. If you edit a file within the directory, the `inode` of the directory isn't touched at all.

But you shouldn't use `/etc/resolver` at all on macOS, it's only kept for backward compatibility. Instead you should create a DNS entry in the Dynamic Store which you can access with the tool `scutil`. Please check out [my reply about this topic](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/385218/99115).

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get `scutil --dns` to return my expected DNS entry until I restarted my computer or forced a refresh of the networking device DNS settings, something like this:

`networksetup -setdnsservers Wi-fi 8.8.8.8`

Wrote down some more detail about this fix/hack here: https://josephharding.github.io/tutorials/2018/06/28/mac-resolver-refresh.html